# генерация временного штампа с ведущим нулём в разряде часов

Tags: windows, cmd

Для формирования уникального имени архива я подставляю в его имя "временной штамп", который получаю следующей конструкцией:

```
@echo off
SET STAMP=%date:~6,4%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%-%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%
echo %STAMP%
```

Но, при использовании до 10:00 am в получаемой строке отсутствует ведущий ноль в часах. Например:

```
2021.04.18- 9.47.18
```

А хотелось бы вот так:

```
2021.04.18-09.47.18
```

Прошу помощи. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

рекомендую воспользоваться промежуточной переменной *HOUR*, с помощью которой и формировать нужное значение часов, заменяя пробел на 0.

```
@echo off
set "HOUR=%TIME:~0,2%"

SET STAMP=%date:~6,4%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%-%HOUR: =0%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%
echo %STAMP%
```